# Linear Algebra Done Right 3.A Exercise Q12

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification, proof-writing

I checked the solution online and they used a different method, so I'm posting this to verify if there are any problems with my proof.

**The Problem.**
Suppose $V$ is finite-dimensional with $\dim V > 0$, and suppose $W$ is infinite-dimensional. Prove that $\mathcal L\left(V, W\right)$ is infinite-dimensional.

**My Solution.** We use proof by contradiction. Assume that $\mathcal L \left(V, W\right)$ is finite-dimensional. We let $$v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_m \in V$$ denote a basis of $V$. Let $$T_1, T_2, \ldots, T_n \in \mathcal L\left(V, W\right)$$denote a basis of $\mathcal L\left(V, W\right)$.

Pick any $w\in W$, we construct a linear map $T$ as follows, $$Tv_j = \begin{cases}w & j=1, \\ 0 & j\neq1.\end{cases}$$
Then by 3.5, $T\in \mathcal L\left(V, W\right)$. Thus, there exist  $$a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n \in F,$$ such that $T = a_1T_1 + \cdots + a_nT_n$. That means $$w = a_1T_1v_1 + a_2T_2v_1 + \cdots + a_nT_nv_1.$$ i.e. $T_1v_1, T_2v_1, \ldots, T_nv_1$ spans $W$. Which contradicts with the fact that $W$ is infinite-dimensional. Therefore, it follows that $\mathcal L\left(V, W\right)$ is infinite-dimensional.

Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: At the end, why does $T_1v_1+T_2v_1+\dots T_nv_1$ span $W?$ Since the construction of $T$ was dependent on $w,$ (and thus the expansion $T=a_1T_1+a_2T_2+\dots a_nT_n$) you won't be able to say every $w$ is represented in this form.

Comment: @PCeltide Although the construction of $T$ was dependent on $w$, $$T_1v_1, \ldots, T_nv_1$$ was not. When you pick a different $w$, there is a different $T$, but it is always a linear combination of $T_1, \ldots, T_n$ isn't it?

Comment: In my opinion your proof is fine. I prefer the direcr proof, based on your reasoning. Let $\{w_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be a linearly independent set in $W.$ Let $v_1,\ldots, v_k$ denote a basis in $V.$ Then the operators $T_n $ defined by $T_nv_k=\delta_{1,k}w_n$ are linearly independent, because $T_nv_1$ are linearly independent.